# Reusable UIView as a nib file

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

I created a Custom UIView called BOHeaderView using xib file. I want this BOHeaderView to be loaded in other UIViewController' xibs.

I tried by adding a UIView in one ViewController nib file and change its type to customView. But I am not able to load the custom view. Below is the initialization code of customView.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BOHeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // commenters report the next line causes infinite recursion, so removing it
    [self customizeHeadView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BOHeaderView" 
                                              owner:[[BOHeaderView alloc] init]
                                            options:nil];
BOHeaderView *infoView = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
infoView.frame = CGRectMake( put your rect here );
[self addSubview:infoView];
```

**EDIT** :

Means you are trying to say : [Using a custom UIView from multiple view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960955/using-a-custom-uiview-from-multiple-view-controllers)

I had the same problem and I solved it in this way :

I wrote the below code on `buttonClick`.

```
 RatingView *rateView = [[RatingView alloc] initWithNibName:@"RatingView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 rateView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,45,1024, 648);
 [self.view addSubview:rateView.view];
```

Happy Coding !!

Comment: The above solution is when you want to load the HeaderView programmatically. I want to load the BOHeaderView in a UIViewController xib file as a subview.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the link you provided. I understand that owner should be BOHeaderView (custom view) itself. Confused on how to use this code and where ? Is it in UIViewController where you are adding it as subview ?

Comment: If I load the custom view in any viewcontroller, programmatically, then the above piece of code is needed. But I am loading the custom view in UIViewController nib file, Should I still have the piece of code you wrote.. Sorry to say its not clear.

Comment: No that code is not at all required. I think you can use the code from the answers given on the link.

Comment: In the link the answere is: If you don't want to create instances of the view in code you could add a "UIView" to your NIB file and set it's class type in the inspector window (command -> 4 -> class dropdown). But this is way not loading in my viewcontroller xib. empty view only i am seeing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22451/discussion-between-sivannarayana-and-bhavin-chitroda)

Comment: @Sivannarayana : I updated my answer. Just see It. I think your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

That row with the `NSBundle` should be in the class in which you want to load the nib. You should write in that class:

`CustomView *customView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BOHeaderView" owner:self options:nil].lastObject;`

It returns an `NSArray`, that is why you need the `lastObjct`